# how to print a char pointer with out getting gibberish?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char, cout

So I'am trying to cout a string of characters which I initialize in a char pointer. The problem is when I cout it, it prints the whole string plus some characters I don't want to see. how would you fix this?

```
string text = "A+B";
char *expression;
expression = new char[text.length()];

for(int x=0;x<text.length();x++)
  expression[x] = text[x];

cout << expression << endl;

It displays this:
   A+B²²²²▌▼∟§s
```

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to insert *null terminator* at the end of your character array:

```
string text = "A+B";
char *expression;
expression = new char[text.length()+1]; //allocate one character more
int x;
for( x=0;x<text.length();x++)
 expression[x] = text[x];
expression[x]=0;  //insert the null terminator
cout << expression << endl;
```

The problem was that, an character array is not considered finished until a *null terminator* is not found.  So it did not stop and was printing beyond actual array. You have to put *null terminator* to mark end of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Your copied string does not contain the terminating zero. That is an objects for example s of type std::string contains s.length() characters that do not include the terminating zero.
The valid code could look as

```
string text = "A+B";
char *expression;
expression = new char[text.length() + 1]; // one more character for the terminating zero
std::strcpy( expression, text.c_str() );
```